# OData Client: What is property UndeclaredPropertyBehavior for

Tags: c#, wcf, client, odata

I have found a new property at the [`DataServiceClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) class: `UndeclaredPropertyBehavior`. But it is not described in MSDN. Does anybody knows what it can be used for?

Comment: What is the question? What is the property?

Comment: As mentioned in the heading, it is the property `UndeclaredPropertyBehavior`. I will edit the question and add the name once more.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of research I found a hint at the [ODataLib](http://odata.github.io/odata.net/#06-13-support-untyped-json). It seems, that the values has the following meaning:

- `UndeclaredPropertyBehavior.None`: DataServiceContext’s old `IgnoreMissing` property is used, for backward compatibility.

Next both options overwrite DataServiceContext’s old `IgnoreMissing`property:

- `UndeclaredPropertyBehavior.Ignore`: always skip undeclared properties
- `UndeclaredPropertyBehavior.Support`: always read undeclared property as either an OData valid value instance or ODataUntyped instance.